# How to submit and display Unicode data(non English) on JSP page

Tags: jsp, unicode, struts2, tomcat7

Greetings for the day. 
i have a jsp page which contains two text areas inside two separate form tags. i want to submit unicode date in one textarea and display it in another. But nothing is working for me. i have to show basically all Indian Languages and english as well. kindly help me. here is the code of it :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page language="java" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("गुजरात के प्राइमरी और हाई स्कूलों में अब वही ");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<%@ include file="navigator.jsp" %>
<s:form action="content.action" method="post" >


<%request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
 <s:textarea name="contentBean.data"  rows="10" cols="100"  />
<s:submit id="submitButton" method="execute" onclick="pressed();" />

        </s:form>

</div> 
   <div>
        <form action="formAction.jsp" method="GET">
            Please enter your text:
            <BR>
            <TEXTAREA NAME="textarea1" ROWS="10" cols="100"><s:property value="contentBean.data" /></TEXTAREA>
            <BR>
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit">

        </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1 :** Remove the first line

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%> // remove this line
```

and put following line in your head tag

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    ...
</head>
```

**Step 2 :** Make sure your jsp page's encoding is `UTF-8`, right click `jsp` page, properties and select `UTF-8` as encoding.

[image: utf-8 image]

**Step 3:** [Optional if you are not using database] If you are using database, make sure the database's collation is `utf-8`, otherwise database will not store your **non English** data.

[image: dbutf8 image]

Comment: Thank you for such a well organised answer.!

Comment: worked for me too. this is a answer what I was looking for.