# Not able to display Hindi Fonts in JSP

Tags: jsp, hindi, property-files

I am trying to display Hindi fonts on JSP through property file. My property file named as **Messages.properties** contains following key-value pairs:

```
basic.title = कृषि ऋण basic.menu1 = ये आपके लिए क्यूँ सही हैं basic.menu2 = ब्लॉग basic.menu3 = टूल
```

My **JSP** code to read this property file is as follows:

```
<%@ page import = "java.util.ResourceBundle" %>
     <% ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Messages");
    String title=resource.getString("basic.title");
    String menu1=resource.getString("basic.menu1");
    String menu2=resource.getString("basic.menu2");
     %>
```

Now I am accessing value of **title** in my JSP as follows

```
<%=title%>
```

But it gives **output** shown in following image:

[image]

I have also follow solution

[given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029077/how-to-submit-and-display-unicode-datanon-english-on-jsp-page)

Please suggest me, what can I do next ?

Comment: make sure you have the right character encodings.

Comment: Yes I have. Its UTF-8